# PHP-based form auto completion with large dataset

Tags: javascript, php, html, sql, autocomplete

I am developing a web application where I have a large (~ 50'000) quantity of text strings (called "items" here) in a SQL database. The user shall select three out of these items in a input form. I tried a few "direct" solutions (Drop-Down combo box, etc.), but these are far too slow with 50'000 items to choose from. Traditional solutions which use JavaScript to implement auto-completion for text boxes suffer from a similar problem: The JavaScript file with the allowed choices becomes far too large (many MiB).

I would prefer to have a solution where the remaining possible items are dynamically fetched from the SQL database while the user types. If, e.g., the first three letters have been typed, only a few hundred possible items will typically remain. However, I have no idea how to implement database access while the user types (without reloading the page, so that PHP code would be executed).

I do not use any content management system; I would prefer a pure HTML/PHP/JavaScript/jQuery/CSS solution that does not rely on bulky third-party libraries. Thanks for your suggestions!

Comment: onchange event, does an AJAX call to the server which queries and proposes matching values.  Do not start this until the user has typed at least 3 chars for example (maybe more).  This avoids searching for all entries with an 'a'!  That being said, expect your question to be closed soon.  Get started with AJAX tutorials, research  a lot, then post here as required .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use php jquery and ajax

```
<form autocomplete="off" action="">
  <div class="autocomplete" style="width:300px;">
    <input id="myInput" type="text" name="myCountry" placeholder="Country">
    <div id="myInputautocomplete-list" class="autocomplete-items">
        //insert ajax response here
    </div>
  </div>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

//css code

```
* { box-sizing: border-box; }
body {
  font: 16px Arial;
}
.autocomplete {
  /*the container must be positioned relative:*/
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
input {
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 16px;
}
input[type=text] {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  width: 100%;
}
input[type=submit] {
  background-color: DodgerBlue;
  color: #fff;
}
.autocomplete-items {
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid #d4d4d4;
  border-bottom: none;
  border-top: none;
  z-index: 99;
  /*position the autocomplete items to be the same width as the container:*/
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
.autocomplete-items div {
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #d4d4d4;
}
.autocomplete-items div:hover {
  /*when hovering an item:*/
  background-color: #e9e9e9;
}
.autocomplete-active {
  /*when navigating through the items using the arrow keys:*/
  background-color: DodgerBlue !important;
  color: #ffffff;
}

<script>
window.addEventListener('load',function(){
        jQuery(document).ready(function($) {   
            $("#myInput").keypress(function() {  
                var inputData = $("#myInput").text('');
                if(inputData.length > 2) {
                    $.ajax({
                        url     : "/ajax.php",
                        type    : "POST",
                        data    : {'myInput': $(this).val()},
                        dataType: 'json',
                        success: function (response) {         
                            //after ajax call here you get the data
                            alert(response.data);
                            // user below divs to iterated data
                            /*
                            <div><strong>D</strong>enmark
                            <input type="hidden" value="Denmark"></div>
                            <div><strong>D</strong>jibouti
                            <input type="hidden" value="Djibouti"></div> */
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Now in ajax.php file

$inputData = $_POST[myInput];

// make sql connection or include connection file

// after connection write query to get data

//suppose table name items

```
$query = "select * from tableName where itemName like $inputData%";
$res = mysql_query($query);
$data = mysql_fetch_data($res);

$result = json_encode("code":200,"data":$data)
return $result;
```